# Route are not defined (Custom function inside Resources Controller) - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I have checkIn function in LoginController:

LoginController.php with Path: `Controllers/Backsite/LoginController`

```
public function checkIn(Request $request, User $user)
{ 
   ...
}
```

Already defined them in web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'backsite', 'as' => 'backsite.', 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function(){
   Route::get('/login/checkIn', [LoginController::class, 'checkIn']);
});
```

I call them from button in blade.php by using:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1" href={{ route('backsite.login.checkIn') }}>CheckIn</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1" href={{ route('backsite.login.checkOut') }}>CheckOut</button>
```

But I shows me error that `Route [backsite.login.checkIn] not defined`.

Im using Laravel 8, and already tried any other I found in Stackoverflow but still giving me Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Route not defined error" occur when you are trying to use route which is not defined please updated your code and defined route in path.

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'backsite', 'as' => 'backsite.', 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function(){
   Route::get('/login/checkIn', [LoginController::class, 'checkIn'])->name('login.checkIn');
});
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I forgot that `name('login.checkIn')`. Thanks for ur help!